# Trying to bring swing frame to front before taking a screenshot but getting artifacts

Tags: java, swing, jframe, always-on-top

I have a part of my app that takes a screenshot of a certain window but before I do so I want to bring the window to the front.  This works fine on my Mac machine but when I tested it on in Windows XP on parallels the screenshot always has a grayed out area where the overlapping window was.  It seems the screenshot is always taken while the window I want on top is being transferred to the top.  I've tried using both:

```
     frame.setVisible(true);
            and
     frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Does anyone have a reasonable solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you post the code fragment that takes the screenshot and calls frame.setVisible(true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to take a screenshot of a window `w` painted by Java, you can just ask it to paint itself on a

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
    w.width, w.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
```

by calling the windows' `paint(g)` method. You can then save the BufferedImage to a file. If you are grabbing an external window, then I believe Oscar Reyes has given you all the answers.

Comment: Awesome this worked perfectly and seems very clean.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

- You could add a delay the the thread that takes the screenshot.
- You could fire the screenshot from the frame when the it has gained focus:

  ```
  class ScreenshotShooter implements FocusListener  {
      public void focusGained( FocusEvent e ) {
          // smile..... 
          // you may add a sec of delay here just be be sure.
      }
      public void focusLost( FocusEvent e ) {}
   }


   FocusListener focusListener = new ScreenshotShooter();
   frame.addFocusListener( focusListener );
   frame.setVisible( true ); // should autofire
   frame.remoe( focusListener);
  ```
- You can do both.

Comment: I tired that but the delay seemed to prolong the time it took for the refresh to occur.  I was thinking I could maybe start a new thread the slept for a certain period of time, and lock that against the screenshot thread, but this all seems very sloppy and would not guarantee success on machines of differing speed.

Comment: Oh definitely that should be in another thread or at least using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() .... Otherwise you stop for a second, take the screenthot and theeen make it visible.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable solution, I'll try that.  Thanks.